# How can I convert a .py to .exe using pmw?

Tags: python, tkinter, import, python-3.8, pmw

I'm building a GUI program in Python 3.8 and I want to convert the Python program to an executable, it always worked. But since I'm using the Python megawidget I can't open the exe file anymore.

I guess the problem is somewhere with installing the pmw.
I did 'pip install pmw' and it says 'Requirement already satisfied' but if I look into the modules there is no pmw.

After converting the Python script to exe using `pyinstaller`, trying to open the exe gives this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: <path_to_script_dir>\\Pmw
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The fix is simple, but which pmw widget did you use?

Comment: Pmw.ScrolledText()
How do I have to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the error is due to Pmw using a lazy import, to fix it try going to [this link](https://github.com/nihaalnz/bundlepmw/blob/master/Pmw.py) and then copy the entire code and create a new file in your project directory(where the python script is located) and then name it `Pmw.py` and then paste this entire code in that file. After that, just just try making an exe. It should work for `Pmw.ScrolledText()`. I had the issue with `Pmw.Balloon()` and this fixed it.

Naming the file to `Pmw.py` overrides the `import Pmw` statement in your code and now this Pmw file is used, which should fix your error with pyinstaller.

**NOTE:** If you are not using other modules like `PmwColor` or `PmwBlt` then make sure to remove the first 10 lines there(which imports those files).

Comment: The link does not work any more. Is there anywhere else I can find it? Thanks in advance

Comment: @jrglez Link doesnt work because on a later push, I removed the file as I stopped using `Pmw`. Anyway you can use the link [here](https://github.com/nihaalnz/bundlepmw/blob/master/Pmw.py) and make sure to remove the first 10 lines.

Comment: Thanks! It worked like a charm. Now I have other problems, but I'm moving forward!