# Error "type object 'Image' has no attribute 'open'

Tags: python, tkinter

So I am trying to have the user upload an image for a flag, but I keep getting the same error "type object 'Image' has no attribute 'open'".
I have looked this up and I can't seem to find the answer. I have tried importing Image as IMG and I get the error "'module' object is not callable". I have tried

```
import PIL.Image
```

and I get the same error.

```
# Imports
from tkinter import * # Tkinter is a GUI toolkit used for Python. This toolkit allows me to create the window and many of the UI options
import Pmw # Pmw stands for 'Python mega widgets'. I imported this primarily for tooltips so the user knows what everything means
from tkinter import Image
from tkinter import filedialog
```

Function the file browser is opened

```
def flagOpener():
        global flagIMG
        flagPath = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select an Image File", filetypes=(("Png Files", "*.png"), ("Jpeg Files", "*.jpg; *.jpeg"), ("All Files", "*.*")))
        flagIMG = Image(Image.open(flagPath))
        flagLabel = Label(image=flagIMG)
```

and the button

```
flagSelect = Button(politicalframe, text = "Select Flag", command=flagOpener())
flagSelect.pack()
```

Comment: ```from PIL import ImageTk,Image; img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("ball.png"))``` what about this ?

Comment: `Image` cannot mean `PIL.Image` and `tkinter.Image` at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Your import statement is messing it up, python is confused between `Image` from `PIL` and `Image` from `tkinter`. What you should do is:

```
import PIL
....

def flagOpener():
    global flagIMG
    flagPath = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select an Image File", filetypes=(("Png Files", "*.png"), ("Jpeg Files", "*.jpg; *.jpeg"), ("All Files", "*.*")))
    flagIMG = Image(PIL.Image.open(flagPath))
    flagLabel = Label(image=flagIMG)
```

Plus, I don't think you should be using `Image` from `tkinter`, use `ImageTk.PhotoImage` from `PIL` and with that all the problems might go away:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
...

def flagOpener():
    global flagIMG
    flagPath = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select an Image File", filetypes=(("Png Files", "*.png"), ("Jpeg Files", "*.jpg; *.jpeg"), ("All Files", "*.*")))
    flagIMG = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(flagPath))
    flagLabel = Label(image=flagIMG)
```

then your button should be:

```
flagSelect = Button(politicalframe, text = "Select Flag", command=flagOpener) # Remove the () so your not calling it immediately
flagSelect.pack()
```

---

Also on a side note, if at all you plan on making an exe later with this code, then `Pmw` will give you all the uncalled errors, so I recommend you make your own tooltip like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63685035/13382000) or tackle the error by following the answer to this post: [How can I convert a .py to .exe using pmw?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63752232/13382000)